# How to push the title of the content to the next page in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have coded PHP script to generate PDF with text contents using TCPDF library. First, the script gets the contents from database and creates temporary .html file. Then the script gets the contents from the .html file and writes to create PDF document.

However, the problem here is it doesn't know when to break a page. So, it looks something like in the image.

I want the script to break the page when the title comes at the bottom of the page and move it to the next page.

There is a function called $pdf->AddPage(); that breaks the page.

Is there any solution to this? Please help.

[image: Picture sample]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) CSS property ? Add this to the DIV which is just above the title. So the style of the above DIV will look something like this.

```
.DIV_CLASS {
      page-break-after: always;
}
```

> The page-break-after property sets whether a page break should occur
>   **AFTER** a specified element or not.

`always` value of the property inserts a page break after the element.

---

**Update:**

To make sure your particular section/DIV doesn't get divided between pages. You can make use of [page-break-inside](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp) property.

Use it like this,

```
.DIV_CLASS {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Above CSS will make sure that `DIV` with class `DIV_CLASS` will never get divided among pages.

> The page-break-inside property sets whether a page break is allowed
>   inside a specified element.

`avoid` value of property avoids page break inside the element (if possible)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. I can easily break the page using $pdf->AddPage(); function. But the problem is how to know when?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, this might help you!

Comment: Thank you Alok, i will definitely try this. :-)

Comment: Great thanks, Please upvote/accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: is it possible to move to the next page only when the element is  the last element

Comment: @NayasSubramanian Maybe you can make use of :last-child CSS property.